# Return body of Symfony Mailer email in a functional test?

Tags: symfony, symfony-mailer

With Mailer, it appears not possible to retrieve the body of an email in a functional test. For example, with

```
$email = $this->getMailerMessage(0);
$body = $email->getBody();
var_dump($body);
```

`$body` is revealed as

> object(Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\Multipart\AlternativePart)...

There are no (apparent) accessible properties of that object. Is there any method for accessing the text of the body of an email sent with Symfony Mailer in a functional test?

With SwiftMailer one could retrieve the body of an email in a functional test with:

```
$mailCollector = $this->client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
$collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
$message = $collectedMessages[0];
$body = $message->getBody();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took quite a while to find this. Backtracked through `assertEmailHeaderSame` to find `assertEmailHtmlBodyContains` then `class EmailHtmlBodyContains` which has `$message->getHtmlBody()`.

So now my test includes `$body = $email->getHtmlBody();`, which is a string. Which can be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's start. At first create MOCK of you service, in your test like this:

```php
$this->mailer = $this->createMock(\Swift_Mailer::class);

self::$container->set('swiftmailer.mailer.default', $this->mailer);
```

after define array variable for your messages in current test

```php
/** @var null|\Swift_Message $emailMessage */
$emailMessages = [];

$this->mailer
    ->method('send')
    ->willReturnCallback(function (\Swift_Message $message) use (&$emailMessages) {
        $emailMessages[] = $message;
    });
```

so, we will catch each email to $emailMessages, you need just to choose needed message and assert its content like:

```php
$emailMessage = $emailMessages[0] ?? null;

$this->assertNotNull($emailMessage);
$this->assertInstanceOf(\Swift_Message::class, $emailMessage);

$body     = $emailMessage->getBody();
$expected = \file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../data/RestController/ServiceController/you_message_body.html');
// do not forget to replace dynamic data in the snapshot.
$body     = \preg_replace('/cid:[a-z0-9]{32}/ui', 'cid_here', $body);
$this->assertEquals($expected, $body);
```

Comment: I recommend to make all mocks in the setUp() method, that's why I use property for MOCK

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please note that the question (and answer) relates to Symfony Mailer, not SwiftMailer.

Comment: the same method, the difference only in service

Comment: What you describe is not a functional test due to the use of MOCK.

Comment: it is MOCK in functional test, you can set MOCK to Symfony container instead of real service. Everything will work as usual, but this service will be MOCK. Have you ever tried to do it? So, let's try!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create services_test.yaml near your services.yaml
   should look like this:

```yaml
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: true

    test.mailer_symfony: '@Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface'
```

2. In the setup method mock real service and change it in the service container

```php
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;

// setUp() 

$this->mailer = $this->createMock(MailerInterface::class);

self::$container->set('test.mailer_symfony', $this->mailer);
```

3. Mock Method send() in you test, according this code https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/5.x/MailerInterface.php it should be something like:

```php
use use Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage;

// ....

/** @var RawMessage[] $emailMessages */
$emailMessages = [];

$this->mailer
    ->method('send')
    ->willReturnCallback(function (RawMessage $message, Envelope $envelope = null) use (&$emailMessages) {
        $emailMessages[] = $message;
    });
```

that's all, you can assert $emailMessages in the end of your test, so, also you can add `expects` and check invocations amount of `send()` method